# jQuery Mobile: Resize SVG to fill window

Tags: jquery-mobile, svg

I am having trouble resizing a SVG to fit inside a jQuery Mobile page.

This should work on mobile devices and also in a normal browser.

Please see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jV3gD/).

```
 <div data-role="content">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://simonamby.dk/wdhtest/img/A_0.svg?id=1"></object>
```

CSS:

```
#map .ui-content {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 40px;
    right    : 0;
    bottom   : 30px;
    left     : 0;
}
```

Bonus: How do I get the fading animation to work in Internet Explorer? Only works in Chrome right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to apply the CSS to the object tag:

```
#map-page object {
    position:absolute;
    top:0%; 
    left:0%; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jV3gD/3/)**

Comment: Works great, thanks! However I forgot I have a list data-role="listview" data-filter-reveal="true" in the top of the content div. Now the image if covering that. How do I get the image to begin right after the searchbox, and fill the whole screen from there? Guessing two divs inside the content div.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with the current problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nnL2y/)

Comment: A step in the right direction, however the dropdown dont work... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simzdk/6AB7P/)

Comment: @Amby, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6AB7P/1/, rset the top of the mapare after each filter event.